# How to plot multiple scatterplots with trendlines as subplots using Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, linear-regression, plotly-python

I'm trying to stack 12 interactive plots showing OLS result and the scattered X and Ys. However, I found it incredibly more difficult than I thought. I successfully drew a single OLS plot (fitted line + scatters) in multiple ways, but putting them together is another story.

So my dataset looks like this:

| ID | tmax01 | tmax02 | tmax03 | ... | ap_tmax01 | ap_tmax02 | ap_tmax03 | ap_tmax04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.12 | 5 | 17 | 19 | 1.10 | 4.5 | 12 | xxx |
| 1 | 2.1 | 2.79 | 20 | Na | 3 | 3.5 | 16 | xxx |
| 2 | -3 | 4 | 18 | 21 | 4 | 4 | 20 | xxx |
| 3 | 6 | 1 | 10 | 26 | 6 | 8 | 10.7 | xxx |
| 4 | -0.5 | 1 | 9 | 14 | 1.0 | 12 | 15 | xxx |

And my 12 OLS models are: tmax01 = beta* ap_tmax01 + e; tmax02 = beta*ap_tmax02 + e; tmax03 = beta* ap_tmax03 +e, etc.

For one plot, I could use:

```
fig4=px.scatter(df, x='ap_tmax01', y='tmax01', trendline="ols")
fig4.data[1].line.color = 'red'
fig4.show()
```

, and the result is:
[image: OLS tmax01]
And I could also use

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
df = df[df['tmax01'].notna()]
df = df[df['ap_tmax01'].notna()]
X = df.ap_tmax01.values.reshape(-1, 1)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, df.tmax01)

x_range = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max(), 100)
y_range = model.predict(x_range.reshape(-1, 1))


subfig_tmax01 = px.scatter(df, x='ap_tmax01', y='tmax01', opacity=0.65)
subfig_tmax01.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x_range, y=y_range, name='Regression Fit'))
subfig_tmax01.show()
```

And it produced similar results.

However, when I tried to stack 2 model results, I got:

[image: Two OLS messed up]

where the fitted line are composed of points. The code I used (which was copied from StackOverflow, pasted, and edited with my best knowledge) was:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig5 = px.scatter(df, x='ap_tmax01', y='tmax01', trendline="ols")
fig6 = px.scatter(df, x='ap_tmax02', y='tmax02', trendline="ols")

fig56 = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

for d in fig5.data:
    fig56.add_trace((go.Scatter(x=d['x'], y=d['y'],  mode='markers')), row=1, col=1)
        
for d in fig6.data:
    fig56.add_trace((go.Scatter(x=d['x'], y=d['y'],  mode='markers')), row=2, col=1)

fig56.show()
```

I'd like to know if there is a good way to draw them without making the fitted lines being made of points, change the legends to the regressed variable names, and make the scattered points showing observation IDs. Thanks!

Comment: To reuse graph information obtained from express, the listed dictionaries can be used as is to reproduce the graphs from express. In addition, the graph name and trendline name can be listed and looped at the same time to be reflected in the legend. An example is the following code. `for d,n in zip(fig5.data, ['Scatter1', 'ols1']):
    fig56.add_trace(go.Scatter(d, name=n, showlegend=True), row=1, col=1)
for d,n in zip(fig6.data, ['Scatter2', 'ols2']):
    fig56.add_trace(go.Scatter(d, name=n, showlegend=True), row=2, col=1)`

Answer (score 1):

If you transform the data a little, you can include `facet_row()` in the `px.scatter()` call to make a facet / trellis plot like in the figure below with this setup:

```
fig = px.scatter(dfs, y = 'regressand', x = 'regressor',
                      facet_row = 'regressand_name',
                      trendline = 'ols',
                      trendline_color_override = 'red')
```

You'll need to do a little clean-up afterwards, but it's all inluded in the code snippet at the end. There's still some potential for improvement, though. The data handling isn't exactly *very* elegant. But it works!

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import cycle
import plotly.express as px
# df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+')
# df.to_dict()
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4},
                 'tmax01': {0: 1.12, 1: 2.1, 2: -3.0, 3: 6.0, 4: -0.5},
                 'tmax02': {0: 5.0, 1: 2.79, 2: 4.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0},
                 'tmax03': {0: 17, 1: 20, 2: 18, 3: 10, 4: 9},
                 'ap_tmax01': {0: 1.1, 1: 3.0, 2: 4.0, 3: 6.0, 4: 1.0},
                 'ap_tmax02': {0: 4.5, 1: 3.5, 2: 4.0, 3: 8.0, 4: 12.0},
                 'ap_tmax03': {0: 12.0, 1: 16.0, 2: 20.0, 3: 10.7, 4: 15.0}})

regressands = [col for col in list(df.columns) if col[0] == "t"]
regressors = [col for col in list(df.columns) if col[0:2] == "ap"]

dfs = pd.DataFrame()
for subsets in list(map(list, zip(regressands, regressors))):
    dfl = df[subsets].copy()
    dfl.columns = ['regressand', 'regressor']
    dfl['regressand_name'] = subsets[0]
    dfl['regressor_name'] = subsets[1]
    dfs = pd.concat([dfs, dfl])

fig = px.scatter(dfs, y = 'regressand', x = 'regressor', facet_row = 'regressand_name',
                 trendline = 'ols',
                 trendline_color_override = 'red')

xNames_cycle = cycle(regressors)
col_cycle = cycle(px.colors.qualitative.Plotly)
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = next(xNames_cycle),
                                      marker_color = next(col_cycle),
                                      showlegend = True) if t.mode == 'markers' else t.update(showlegend = False))

yTitle = cycle(regressands)
fig.for_each_yaxis(lambda yx: yx.update(title = next(yTitle)))
fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text = '' if 'regressand' in a.text else ()))

fig.show()
```